# Not able to understand the inheritance and overriding/overloading in java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have problem understanding the below code(commented against the line number)

```
class Base {
    void m1(Object o) {
    }

    void m2(String o) {
    }
}

public class Overloading extends Base {

    void m1(String s) {
    }

    void m2(Object o) {
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new Object();
    Base base1 = new Base();
    base1.m1("");//**why this works perfect**
    Base base = new Overloading();
    base.m2(o);// **why compile time error** - The method m2(String) in the type Base is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

Answer (score 7):

Compiler always resolves the method invocation based on the declared type of the reference you invoke it on.

When you invoke the method:

```
base1.m1("");
```

compiler looks for the method signature in declared type of `base1`, which is `Base` in this case. The matching method in `Base` is:

```
void m1(Object o) { }
```

Since parameter `Object` can accept a `String` argument, the invocation is valid. You can pass a subclass object to a superclass reference.

---

Now, with 2nd invocation:

```
base.m2(o);
```

again the declared type of `base` is `Base`. And the matching method in `Base` class is:

```
void m2(String o) { }
```

Since you cannot pass an `Object` reference where a `String` is accepted. The compiler gives you compiler error. There is no implicit narrowing conversion.

---

You can understand it more clearly with a simple assignment:

```
Object ob = new Integer(3);
String str = ob;  // This shouldn't be valid
```

Java doesn't perform implicit narrowing conversion. The assignment from `obj` to `str` shouldn't be valid, because else you would get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: Can we say that because String is a sub type of Object it works in first case but as Object is not sub type of String the second one fails?

Comment: @Prateek. yes you can say it like that.

Comment: @RohitJain can we pass any type of object in the first invocation void m1(Object o) { } as every class extends Object class ?

Comment: @Naroji. Yes. You can. And you can even pass primitives, which will involve boxing then widening.

Answer (score 4):

At the line `base.m2(o)`, the compiler doesn't know that `base` is an `Overloading` -- it only knows that it is a `Base`.  Why has it forgotten?  Because you *told it to.*

You *told* the compiler to treat `base` as a `Base`, by declaring it with `Base base = ...`.

So, as per your instructions, the compiler will treat `base` as a `Base` without knowing anything about any subclass of `Base` it might or might not extend, and it (correctly) points out that `base` might not support `m2` on an arbitrary `Object`.