# Child objects and parent objects being passed into the same method

Tags: java, methods, arguments, extends, subclassing

I have a custom `QuadBatch` method, which as the name suggests, batches up quads to be drawn with one openGL call.

I have 2 objects, which are created as follows:

```
QuadBatch sprite1 = new QuadBatch();

NewSprite sprite2 = new NewSprite();
```

This is where `QuadBatch` is the parent class, and `NewSprite` is a subclass of it (ie, it extends `QuadBatch`).

I did this because `NewSprite` required everything in the `QuadBatch` class, but also some extra stuff.

If I have an animate method which takes a `NewSprite` object like so:

```
public void animate(NewSprite newSprite){

//animation code here

}
```

How can I use this same method but passing in a `QuadBatch` object?  I can't just pass in a `QuadBatch` object as the method expects a `NewSprite` object.

The same question applies in reverse if the argument taken by the animate() method was a `QuadBatch` object.  How could I pass in a `NewSprite` object?

Comment: Check this recent post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/18902307/1679863

Comment: If the method had a `QuadBatch` parameter, there is no problem, you can pass `NewSprite`.

Comment: To expand on @SotiriosDelimanolis, methods that accept a class will accept any subclass as well. For example, a method that takes a java.lang.Number will accept a java.lang.Double or a java.lang.Integer or even a java.math.BigDecimal. This is part of what polymorphism is all about, and it's a key part of OO programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have your method take the parent class as the parameter...

```
public void animate(QuadBatch param) {

  // animation code here

  //if you need specific method calls you could cast the parameter here to a NewSprite
  if (param instanceof NewSprite) {
      NewSprite newSprite = (NewSprite)param;
      //do NewSprite specific stuff here
  }

}

//However, hopefully you have a method like doAnimate() on QuadBatch 
//that you have overloaded in NewSprite
//and can just call it and get object specific results

public void animate(QuadBatch param) {

  param.doAnimate();

}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this - thanks, makes perfect sense.

Comment: I really, *really* hope that OP doesn't do the first version of animate() that you listed, because that's a hack that breaks object-orientation in a way that should be reserved only for extreme cases.

Comment: Agreed, which is why it was essentially written as a "you can do this, but I hope you do this..."

Answer (score 1):

If your animate() method doesn't require any calls that are on the NewSprite object but not on the QuadBatch object, then simply change the parameter type to QuadBatch.

```
public void animate(QuadBatch quadBatch) {
  // animation code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.`How can I use this same method but passing in a QuadBatch object? I can't just pass in a QuadBatch object as the method expects a NewSprite object.`

`animate()` method expects `NewSprite`  object so you can't pass the `QuadBatch` object to it,since `QuadBatch` is not of type `NewSprite`.

2.`The same question applies in reverse if the argument taken by the animate() method was a QuadBatch object. How could I pass in a NewSprite object?`

You can pass `NewSprite` object as argument to `animate(QuadBatch)` method since `NewSprite` is a type of `QuadBatch`(`NewSprite` extends `QuadBatch`).

Comment: NewSprite is-a QuadBatch. This is why knowing what an is-a relationship is is good. If a NewSpite IS A QuadBatch, then why can't I use it like one? Everything becomes intuitive just off knowing terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method argument to QuadBatch object

```
public void animate(QuadBatch quadBatch ){

//animation code here

}
```

You can create an object of subclass using reference of parent class :

```
QuadBatch quadBatch = new NewSprite();
```